# Remove current_page_parent from posts page link in WordPress nav menu

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I have set a page to be the posts page. So when I visit single posts the link for posts page in nav menu has a class 'current_page_parent'.

But when I visit single posts for a custom post type, then also it is adding 'current_page_parent' to the link for posts page.

How can I restrict it and not add the class when I visit single custom post types page.

Comment: I think this might help you out: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/206536/105535

Comment: @Fayaz `current_page_parent` is a classname WordPress adds.

Comment: @DavidLee thanks for the info. I need to spend more time on theme stuffs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assuming you're using [wp_page_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_page_menu/) or [wp_list_pages()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/).  If so, then what you need to do is hook into the [page_css_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_css_class/) filter, e.g.,

```
add_filter ('page_css_class', 'my_func', 10, 5) ;

function
my_func ($classes, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page_id)
{
    if (/* test condition */) {
        $classes = array_diff ($classes, array ('current_page_parent')) ;
        }

    return ($classses) ;
}
```

where `/* test condition */` is where you'd put your logic to decide when that class should be included.

Comment: thanks for the code. I used the `nav_menu_css_class` hook to solve the issue